# Angular JS: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I am not sure what i am doing wrong here -

```
function clearBefore(val) {
                if (val.isEnrolled && val.name === 'XYZ') {
                    vm.clear(val, 'Hello').then(function(value){
                        return value;
                    });
                    return true;
                }
            }
```

then calling it -

```
clearBefore(val).then(function (returnVal) {});
```

I am new to promises, please let me know how the function should be updated to return a promise.

Comment: `vm.clear(val, 'Hello').then(function(value)` What is `vm`?

Comment: Does `vm.clear` return a promise?

Comment: No it does not return any promise

Comment: So you cannot use `vm.clear(...).then(...)` and/or directly `return vm.clear(...)`. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the "if" you are returning "true" and outside the "if" you are returning nothing so you cannot use the return of clearBefore() as a promise.

Maybe this is what you want:

```
function clearBefore(val) {
  if (val.isEnrolled && val.name === 'XYZ') {   
    return $q.resolve(vm.clear(val, 'Hello'));
  }

  return $q.reject();
}

clearBefore(val).then(
  function(val) {
    console.log('ok', val);
  },
  function() {
    console.log('not ok...');
  }
);
```

Now every return point of the function returns a promise. We have a `$q.resolve()` inside the "if" and a `$q.reject()` outside to return a failed promise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return your promise

> ```
> function clearBefore(val){
>      if (val.isEnrolled && val.name === 'XYZ')
>      {   
>          return vm.clear(val, 'Hello').then(function(value)
>          { 
>               return value; 
>          }); 
>          return true; 
>       } 
> }
> ```

something like this

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't return anything at the end of the clearBefore() function, so try to do so:

```
function clearBefore(val) {
                if (val.isEnrolled && val.name === 'XYZ') {
                    vm.clear(val, 'Hello').then(function(value){
                        return value;
                    });
                }
              return val; // here you should return what you need
            }
```

and after that this:

```
clearBefore(val).then(function (returnVal) {});
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue i did something like following (introduced promise to the function)

```
function clearOTPBefore(page) {
                return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
                    if (val.isEnrolled && val.name === 'XYZ') {
                        return vm.clear(val, 'Hello').then(function(value){
                            return resolve(value);
                        });
                    } else {
                        resolve(true);
                    }

                })
            }
```